# Template parameter deduction with function pointers and references

Tags: c++, templates, reference, function-pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are qualifiers of template arguments stripped when deducing the type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164451/why-are-qualifiers-of-template-arguments-stripped-when-deducing-the-type)

Consider the following C++ code:

```
void f(int&);

template <typename T> void tpl(void (*)(T), T);

void bar(int& x)
{
        tpl(&f, x);
}
```

Compilation using GCC 4.6.0 fails with the following error message:

```
fntpl.cpp: In function ‘void bar(int&)’:
fntpl.cpp:7:11: error: no matching function for call to ‘tpl(void (*)(int&), int&)’
fntpl.cpp:7:11: note: candidate is:
fntpl.cpp:3:46: note: template<class T> void tpl(void (*)(T), T)
```

If I state the template parameters explicitely (`tpl<int&>(&f, x)`), it works. Why doesn't template argument deduction work in this case?

Comment: The type of the expression `x` is `int`, not `int &` (references decay to lvalues whenever they are used in an expression). The compiler error message seems to be misleading at best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because these are fundamentally different

```
void f(int&);
```

and

```
void (*)(T)
```

the compiler has only deduced that `T` is `int`, so it looks for:

```
void f(int);
```

which is nothing like your intention, change the function pointer to this:

```
template <typename T> void tpl(void (*)(T&), T);
```

And the compiler will be happy...